# How to Save Data from Controller to a Place. So, I can Use It to All Controllers or Views in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

Example, I want to save $id below to be global variable. So, I can use it in all controllers or views in Laravel framework. The function is like SharedPreferences in Android.

I have tried using Config::set('courseId', $id). But, its only work in view of its controller(pages.teacher.class.dashboard-class-study). When I call it in another view, it is empty.

```
class StudyController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
            
            $item = Course::findOrFail($id);
            $theories = Theory::WHERE('subpart', $item->subpart)->get();

            return view('pages.teacher.class.dashboard-class-study', [
                'items' => $theories,
                'idCourse' => $id,
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. What do you mean by "place"? a database? a cache? a file?

Comment: it's like sharedpreferences in Android

Comment: Try updating your question with more information about what you are trying to accomplish. What systems you are trying to support, what you currently have for your database storage, etc, etc. Without this sort of context it will make it very hard for someone to help you!

Comment: I have tried using Config::set('courseId', $id). But, its only work in view of its controller(pages.teacher.class.dashboard-class-study). When I call it in another view, it is empty.

Comment: are you trying to have something persist between different requests for the same user? or just something that is always available to every request?

Comment: It is for the same user

Comment: sounds like a good candidate for using the session

Comment: Thank you. It works by using Session https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session